# Can I get IIS log to cs-host when used as a load balancer

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I've configured an IIS machine with load balancing using URL Rewrite and a Server Farm.
The site handles multiple URLs to and then hands them off to one of the backend servers, but still using SSL. This means the backend servers only get their own hostname (e.g. foo1.server.com or foo2.server.com) and the various front end urls (e.g. foo.server.com, bar.server.com) are handled by the load balancer.

However the loadbalancer won't log cs-host. If I turn this field on, it shows in the list of headers, but then each line only has a '-' character where the hostname should be. This means I can't work out which of the URLs are still being used and which I can potentially remove safely.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement, if you want to get cs-host in the log, then you only need to check `Host(cs-host)` in iis ->logging -> Select Fields...

Comment: Exactly that - however when I turn that on, on the load balancer - then the logs don't have it.  The log "header" which lists all the fields includes cs-host, but in that position on each log line all it logs is a "-" character, just before the response status.

Comment: You can try to create a custom response header with your sitename and add a custom field to log the sitename response header, then check if the Host (cs-host) in your logs is still '-' character.